# PHP: How to cache a big table in redis?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, redis

Assume, that I have a big (MySQL-)table (>10k rows) with id -> string. I can put them all in an array and cache this array. But the question ist: How to cache it efficiently?

**a) Cache it as one big item**. So I will execute

```
$redis->set("array", $array);
```

Quite short and easy. But for every entry I need, I have to fetch the whole thing. Absolutely inefficient.

**b) Cache every entry itself**:

```
foreach( $array as $id => $str )
  $redis->set( "array:$id", $str );
```

Using this way, I will have >10k entries in Redis. That doesn't feel good. If I have 10 of these tables, i will have 100k entries....

So what's your proposal? How to cache a big array?

Comment: Use case: I need exactly one entry at a time.

Comment: Why do you need to cache an entire database table in Redis, why not simply use the data from the original database table?

Comment: 1) The id and the string are only two of the columns. 2) The database is high-traffic and I want to reduce the load. 3) Isn't that the sense of a cache - to buffer the DB-Data if used often? 4) Redis is memory-only and located on the machine of the webserver, the DB is on its own machine in a cluster.

Comment: Well Databases have their own caching for frequently accessed records; but if the database is high traffic then ensure it is properly indexed - external caching can be beneficial for storing the results of regular, relatively static queries that take a long time to run, but if the db access isn't slow (depends on your query), but a simple indexed query that retrieves a single record without aggregates/etc shouldn't be any slower than a redis access...

Comment: ... Even though your redis is physically on the same server, it's still requested as through a network request, so the only thing you'd be saving is the network latency; but adding the overheads of caching validation, fallback on a miss, etc

Comment: Mark Baker: I thank you a lot! You gave me arguments to rethink my design.

Comment: I'm currently wrestling with similar arguments myself, though perhaps I started a couple of days earlier so I've had longer to think some of it through :)

Comment: I see. :) There is some logic in your arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caching the big array only makes helpful if you're planning to retrieve it always as a whole. However cache invalidation will be a very "heavy" operation as anytime when you change something you have to invalidate the whole array and reread it from the DB.

10k in redis is not much at all. You can have millions of entries without problem.

I would go with the b) version. Cache every entry individually. Easier to maintain, simpler application code and smaller memory footprint from application side which gets more and more important when you want to scale your application.

Comment: I like your answer - I'll give it a try! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The first question is: why do you need to cache that array.

If you allways need the whole array, then:

```
$redis->set("array", $array);
```

If you only need some specific indexes (2nd solution), then why are you trying to cache the whole thing instead of querying the database each time for the id you need.
It is allways more efficient to get only needed data.

Remember that a cache usefullness is estimmated using the ration between reads (items effectively read from the cache) and miss (items read from the datasource then added to the cache).

If you are caching the whole table (10k miss), but querying only few elements by id (2de solution), then your ratio is near zero.
If you need the whole table each time, then cache it using the first solution (1miss) and so your ratio is more likely to be > 1.

Also, remember that redis is a separate server. For each request to redis, a request is made to this server (on localhost or not).
So basicly it's the same rule for redis than for mysql: One big request will perform faster than many little requests.

Comment: I dont need the whole array. I need exactly one entry at a time.

Comment: Then, go for the second solution. When you need an entry, get it from the cache. If it is not in the cache, get it from the db and store it in the cache. But don't load the whole table in the cache as soon as the application start, let it lazy load to the cache only when needed.

Comment: But 10k times "select field from table where id = ?" is much heavier load than one time "select id, field from table" and cache these ... isn't it?

Comment: The purpose of lazy loading is that you load only what you need at a given time.
So event if 10k Select is heavyer, they are distributed in time (minutes or even hours depending on your application usage)
More information about eager loading vs lazy loading: http://codingatilivedigitally.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/lazy-loading-vs-eager-loading/